# Видеоконференцсвязь - как пишется?

Tags: орфография

Где-то дается слитное написание, а где-то - через дефис все три слова.

Что верно?

Answer (score 3):

**Видео-конференц-связь** согласно [Орфографическому словарю:](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%E2%E8%E4%E5%EE%EA%EE%ED%F4%E5%F0%E5%ED%F6%F1%E2%FF%E7%FC)

Первая часть сложных слов *видео-* пишется слитно, но слитное написание заменяется дефисным, если вторая часть начинается с прописной буквы или пишется через дефис. Здесь вторая часть (конференц-связь) с дефисом, так как *конференц*  - усеченная основа самостоятельно употребляющегося существительного.

Answer (score 2):

"Видео-конференц-связь" можно найти только в орфографическом словаре. Все остальные источники используют слитное написание, например из Википедии: "Видеоконференцсвязь - это современные технологии коммуникации между людьми, которые находятся на большом расстоянии". А у нас вообще есть подобные слова или это прецедент?

И почему конференц-связь, конференц-зал пишутся через дефис. Обычные сложносокращенные слова, чем они лучше, к примеру, чем "запчасти,стройотряд"? И теперь одно исключение накладывается на другое исключение.

Comment: Да, я тоже за слитное написание. Вполне логично и традиционно.

Answer (score 0):

Видеоконференц-связь... Читайте законы.

Comment: А законы для русского языка кто издает?

Answer (score 0):

Видео-конференц-связь. Именно так написано в федеральных законах.